# Show that $\exists B_1,B_2 \in SO(2, \Bbb R)$ such that $A(t)= B_1 \begin{pmatrix} e^{\delta} &0 \\ 0 &e^{-\delta} \end{pmatrix} B_2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory

> Let $t \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$ and let $A(t)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &t \\ 0 &1 \end{pmatrix}$. Show that $\exists B_1,B_2 \in SO(2, \Bbb R)$ such that $A(t)= B_1 \begin{pmatrix} e^{\delta} &0 \\ 0 &e^{-\delta} \end{pmatrix} B_2$ for some $\delta \ge 0$

Since, any element of $SO(2, \Bbb R)$ is of the form $\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta &\cos \theta \end{pmatrix}$, I just computed $$\begin{pmatrix} \cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta &\cos \theta \end{pmatrix} A(t)\begin{pmatrix} \cos \phi &-\sin \phi \\ \sin \phi &\cos \phi \end{pmatrix}$$And I obtained that $$\cos(\theta+\phi)+t\cos\theta\sin\phi \ge 1 \dots (1)$$ $$t\cos\theta\cos\phi-\sin(\theta+\phi)=0 \dots (2)$$ $$t \sin \theta \sin\phi+\sin(\theta+\phi)=0 \dots(3)$$ $$\cos(\theta+\phi)+t\sin\theta\cos\phi=\frac{1}{\cos(\theta+\phi)+t\cos\theta\sin\phi } \dots (4)$$

Expanding $(4)$ and plugging in $(2),(3)$ I got that $$2 \sin^2(\theta+\phi) - t \sin(\theta+\phi)cos(\theta+\phi)=0$$ $$\implies \sin(\theta+\phi)=0 \text{ or, } \tan(\theta+\phi)=\frac{t}{2} \dots (5)$$

Also combining $(2),(3)$ we have that $$\sin\theta\sin\phi=-\cos\theta\cos\phi \implies \cos(\theta - \phi)=0 \implies (\theta - \phi) = (2n+1)\frac{\pi}{2} $$

Combining this with $\theta+\phi=\tan^{-1}(\frac{t}{2}) \text{ or } \theta+\phi=n\pi$ , does it finish?

Or if anyone can give a better alternative solution, it would be extremely helpful! Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: are you familiar with SVD?  That's really what the problem is (plus information from the determinant)... Do you need to explicitly parameterize your diagonal matrix and orthogonal matrices by t?

Comment: @user8675309 Can you kindly write an answer clearly stating what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVD tells us
$A_t = U\Sigma V^T$

where $\Sigma$ is diagonal with real non-negative entries on the diagonal ordered from largest to smallest and $U$ and $V^T$ are orthogonal. Note

$1=\Big\vert\det\big(A_t\big)\Big\vert = \Big\vert\det\big(U\Sigma V^T\big)\Big\vert = \Big\vert\det\big(U\big)\Big\vert\cdot \Big\vert\det\big( \Sigma\big)\Big\vert \cdot \Big\vert\det\big( V^T\big)\Big\vert = 1 \cdot \Big\vert\det\big( \Sigma\big)\Big\vert \cdot 1$

$\Sigma$'s determinant modulus of 1 gives us its determinant (since it is diagonal with real non-negative entries) and either
(a) $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 =1$  or
(b) $\sigma_1\gt 1\gt \sigma_2 \gt 0$
check the squared Frobenius norm:
$\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2 =\big\Vert A_t\big\Vert_F^2 = 1+1+t^2 \gt 2$
which rules out (a) and we thus have (b), so $\Sigma =   \begin{pmatrix} e^{\delta} &0 \\ 0 &e^{-\delta} \end{pmatrix} $ for some $\delta \gt 0$

revisiting the determinant
$1=\det\big(A_t\big)= \det\big(U\Sigma V^T\big) = \det\big(U\big)\cdot 1\cdot \det\big( V^T\big) $
thus orthogonal matrices $U$ and $V^T$ either
(a) both have determinant $+1$ or
(b) both have determinant $-1$.

If (a) then we're done, so suppose it's (b) and use the type 3 elementary matrix
$D:=\begin{pmatrix} 1 &0 \\ 0 &-1\end{pmatrix}$
noting that $D^TD =D^2=I$ and instead consider
$A_t= U\Sigma V^T= UI\Sigma V^T = U\big(DD\big)\Sigma V^T = \big(UD\big)\Sigma DV^T = \big(UD\big)\Sigma \big(VD\big)^T = B_1 \Sigma B_2$

Comment: This is just a special case for the Polar decomposition of semi-simple lie groups right?